# “Tables 1 and 2” or “Table 1 and 2”

Tags: academic-life, tables

In an academic thesis would you rather use *"tables 1 and table 2"* than *"table 1 and 2"*?

Comment: "Tables" because there are two of them.

Comment: English Language Learners SE is better for this question. VTC.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Either “tables 1 and 2” or “table 1 and table 2” would be correct.